# Refit [FromQuery] with custom class not getting values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, refit

I'm having a problem with a Get method in my Web API: The API gets the object but with the default values.

For instance:

```
myRefitClient.GetSummary(new MyClass() { Prop = 1 });
```

**The Web API correctly receives a `MyClass` instance, but `Prop` is 0!**

This is all that I have:

The Get method (Controller in the Web API):

```
[HttpGet]
async Task<ActionResult> Get([FromQuery]MyClass req)
```

MyClass is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

and my Web API interface for Refit is:

```
public interface IMyWebApi
{
    [Get("/api/mycontroller")]
    Task<PositionSummary> GetSummary(MyClass req);
}
```

So, as I said, upon the call:

```
service.GetSummary(new MyClass() { Prop = 1 });
```

I'm getting a `MyClass` Instance in my Controller, but Prop is 0, instead of 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried  `[FormUri]` instead of `[FromQuery]`

Comment: Check also what is the actual url value was in your controller using `Request` (`Request.RequestUri`)

Answer (score 6):

To force ASP.NET Web API (not ASP.NET Core) to read a complex type from the URI, add the [`[FromUri]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri) attribute to the parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get([FromUri]MyClass req)
```

If you are using ASP.NET Core then use [`[FromQuery]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#sources) attribute

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get([FromQuery]MyClass req)
```

> I'm getting a MyClass Instance in my Controller, but Prop is 0,
>   instead of 1.

If `/api/mycontroller` is set as launchUrl in launchSettings.json then you will get MyClass Instance with Prop = 0 at the start of application. But next call using Refit should pass parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is model binding. The way refit serializes your object and how API serialization/deserialization works should match. Refit has serialization settings, you need to adjust. can you look it that?

Take a look at :
https://reactiveui.github.io/refit/

Under JSON content section.

Similarly, your API should work with the same serialization settings. You can configure it at your services in `Startup.cs`

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to implement IFormattable. Found that after going through the Refit source code, weird it's not documented.

Comment: please provide a meaningfull sample of code so SuperJMN can try it out in his application.